# In a table each row has an edit button. Show or hide the button depends on another value in this row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table defined in js file, last column is an edit button for each row, to let user edit this row's information. There's another row, the third row, MlsCode. Only when the value of MlsCode is "A" or "B", we should show the edit button in this row. Below is a part of the table builder:

```
var agentSearchResultBuilder = 
[
    { colName: "First Name", dataName: "FirstName" },
    { colName: "Last Name", dataName: "LastName" },
    { colName: "MLS", dataName: "MlsCode" }, 
    {
        colName: "MLS Office Status",
        dataName: "Office.MlsIsActive",
        template: '{{if Office.MlsIsActive}}Active{{else}}Inactive{{/if}}',
        styleClass: '{{if Office.MlsIsActive}}active{{else}}inactive{{/if}}'
    },
    {
        colName: "Edit",
        template: "<button title='Edit Agent Information' class='tinyButton editAgent' id='${MlsCode}'>Edit</button>"
    }
];
```

I wrote following code to control the edit button visibility, but only the first matching row can show the button. The later matching rows didn't show the button. I don't know what's wrong.

```
$("button.editAgent", table).button().hide(); //to hide all buttons initially

$('#agentSearchTable >tbody >tr').each(function () {
            var value = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
            if (value === "A") {
                $("#A").show();
                alert(value);
                 /*I use this to test if it reaches every
                    matching row or not. Turns out yes. Each matching row 
                    gives alert. But edit button didn't show(only first 
                    matching one shows.)
                  */
            }
            if (value === "B") {
                $("#B").show();
                alert(value);
            }
        });
```

Also, I noticed in the agentSearchResultBuilder, there's some code like {if}..{/if}, so I wonder is there a way that I can simply do this in the template of my edit button. Like if the id equals 'A' or 'B', display button. I am totally new to C#, javascript and jQuery. This is my first project. Hope you could help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Add the markup, better to add a FIDDLE.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Show the table HTML what you have been working on.

Comment: there's only one line in html, like this:

Comment: <table id="agentSearchTable" style="clear: both;" class="resultsTable highlightRows tablesorter"></table>         the table is generate somewhere else.

Comment: @YabinSong please use a snippet or a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$("#A").show();
```

isn't going to work, because it depends on having the same id on buttons in multiple rows, which isn't legal HTML.  The browser is probably ignoring the `id` attributes with ids it's already seen.  You probably want to use a class, rather than an id (add `button-${MLSCode}` to the end of your `class` attribute and remove the `id` attribute), and use something like this:

```
$(this).find('.button-a').show();
```

to show it.

Comment: hi, thank you very much, this actually works. but I got another problem. I can't hide all the button first by the class attribute. now all buttons show by default. I test your code by setting '.button-a' hide, and it works. all matching buttons hide, others show. But how can I make those buttons hide by default?

Comment: @YabinSong: Mea culpa, you already had a `class` attribute.  You need to only have one, so just add the new class to your existing one list (the list of classes is space-separated) and remove the `id` attribute.